How to set the time column result returned by Apache IoTDB to a string data type?
Does the time column in the Apache IoTDB query result have to be a timestamp? Can I specify the data type of time returned? Such as for original data column 1710972000000, I hope it will be returned as a string, like 2024-03-21 06:00:00+08:00. Is this supported in IoTDB and how can I set the configuration to achieve this?

Specifiying the data type of timestamp in Apache IoTDB is currently not supported yet. Related conversion functions for timestamp columns will be provided in the future.
